# how do you reverse a string in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, string, linq, reverse

I was reading an old post from coding horror (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/why-cant-programmers-program.html) It's still a very entertaining read, you'll notice a lot of the people providing answers actually made small logical errors themselves (about 30% of them).

Anyway, thought I'll set myself a small challenge and found a bunch of fizzbuzz questions here: [Alternate FizzBuzz Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117812/alternate-fizzbuzz-questions)

"Reverse a String" - with all the built-in methods in the .net framework there are many ways to do this.

My question is:
1. **how do you reverse a string using LINQ?** 
2. can you come up with other interesting ways of reversing a string in C#?

Here's are two examples I came up with 
1. completely from scratch
2. using enumerable's reverse methods (1 liner)

```
    private static string FromScratchSimplified(string input)
    {
        // constructed reversed char array
        char[] reversedCharArray = new char[input.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            reversedCharArray[i] = input[input.Length-1-i];
        }

        // build string from char array
        string reversedString = new String(reversedCharArray);

        return reversedString;
    }


    private static string UsingEnumerableReverseMethod(string input)
    {
        // using Enumerable.Reverse method
        return new String(input.Reverse().ToArray());
    }
```

Any more?

Comment: This might be better suited to codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: I like this question, but it's not for StackOverflow. -1.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that this post be down-voted so much. I think he is just interested in how to reverse a string using LINQ. @James Z, please consider editing the post so that it sounds more like a question than a challenge.

Comment: when I want to reverse a string I send it to a certificate secured web service and then geo-replicate the result....

Comment: this seem like a very harsh community. 4 down votes within a few minutes of posting here, and this is like the second time i ever posted a question here.

Comment: Thanks @ByteBlast, I'll reword it to be a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep it as close to query syntax as possible:

given:

```
        string aString = "please reverse me";
```

then:

```
        var reversed = new string((from c in aString.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                            orderby c.index descending
                            select c.value).ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine(reversed);
```

yields:

```
em esrever esaelp
```

Comment: This is actually the answer I was looking for I.e. with query syntax. Will try it out and if it works and there's no more posts I'll accept ur answer

Answer (score 1):

```
new string(Enumerable.Range(1, input.Length).Select(i => input[input.Length - i]).ToArray())
```